Movie with two planet fighting between them
I see this old movie,once,so i don't remind too much
There are two planet/races called one Albany and the oter Pax
a man fought for Pax(their people dress like ancient romans)
but fall in love with a woman of Albany and then take the part
of albany people,but Pax agents tried to recover him.
This man discover on Albany the dissident were tortured and
enslaved,if wrong thing happen they will punished with a strange
"teaser" called "Stick of pleasure and pain" (please don't laugh)
I don't remind other.
Release year: 1983-94
Genre:  Fantastic
Format: probably TV movie
Country: USA
Other info: rare

'"Stick of pleasure and pain" (please don't laugh)' made my day. Have an upvote.

The date is wrong, and there's no Albany as far as I can tell, but it's barely possible you are referring to Gene Roddenberry's Genesys II from 1973, or one of its sequels (Planet Earth, Strange New World). These feature an organization named PAX, and take place in a future Earth (in the United States, but on the west coast - although it is possible Albany is mentioned somewhere). Genesys II includes Roman togas, and Planet Earth has a matriarchal society where men are enslaved.

Yes it is,i remind albany but probably is wrong,i've see this movie only once,and over 15 years ago,so probably i'm a little confused.
